# Modal Popup not firing in C#

Tags: c#, ajax, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have been trying to get a Modal Popup to work for the last few months.  I try and try, and after a while I just give up and find another way to work around it.  I am very new to programming and have been doing some helpful things for my department, but in order to make these things viable alternatives I need to get more functionality out of them.
I want to be able to update a row in my SQL server, but the gridview is pulling data from a View, so the built in edit options won't work for me.  I was hoping to be able to have a Modal Popup appear on the screen so that I can have the user put the data in and it will build the proper SQL statement to update the row.
I can't even get a Modal Popup with a single line of text to 'popup' though. 
At the top of the page I have this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Then in my main div I have this:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat=server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Then down in the body I have this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
<cc1:ModalPopExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupcontrolID='pnlEdit" TargetControlID=btnTest" OkControlID="btnSubmit" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackroundCssClass="modalBackground" ></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEdit" runat="server" style="display:none">
  <div class="modalPopup>
  <p>Text goes here.</p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="sever" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="sever" Text="Close" />
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind currently has nothing for this.  I have tried the same code with the variation of giving the btnTest an OnClick that does mp1.Show();.  And also tried adding a "dummy" TargetControlID that is rendered but not shown in order to use the Code Behind to fire.

Every variation produces the same results.  The "Test" button is clicked and then nothing happens.  It appears that the page is reloaded.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you ever considered to use Bootstrap modal? [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: I can see that you have some typos in your codes. Most of the opening and closing `"` are missing. For example: You've got `ID=ToolkitScriptManager1"` it should be `ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"` and etc.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will double check that stuff, I had to hand type it since I can't use my work computer to access these forums.

Comment: Those typos would cause compiler/build issues though so I am pretty sure the code in the actually application is good.

Comment: Are you trying to open the modal from Gridview?

Comment: That's the endgame intent, but right now I just want to see the pop-up show up so I have the button right on the page.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [Solution](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Use-AJAX-Modal-Popup-Extender-inside-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: This article will be great when I get the Modal Popup to work and need to start working on getting it to work with my GridView and updating my database, but I went through the article and updated my code and I still can't see the popup.